# Smart Card (CAC) Authentication in Webview with UWP

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, uwp, smartcard

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction..

I'm trying to make the transition from C# in Winforms to UWP. The main obstacle is that in Winforms when visiting websites that require certificate authentication from a Smart Card or CAC the Webbrowser Control will automatically challenge users for a PIN code. I'm looking for the same functionality in UWP where users can use the Webview control and when trying to access websites that require it, the app will prompt users for it.

I've been researching this for quite a while now so if you have any experience with handling certificates in UWP your wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The WebView should be able to popup the smart card authentication. I've tested this scenario in my project which targets platform is 15063

Comment: That's good news! Perhaps its something I'm not seeing.. Are you using Visual Studio Community? What capabilities have you enabled? Is there something I need to manually handle in order for users to be challenged with their PIN? What framework are you targeting? Is there something that needs to be added to the manifest file? The error the server gives me is that the challenge was canceled even though it never challenged with a PIN. Thank you again!

Comment: I even have not enable any extra capabilities. I'm using visual studio 2017 enterprise.